# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync throws ArgumentNullException exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using Microsoft Identity for users.
When I try to sign in SignInManager throws exception.

Here's the exception :

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, string propertyKey, string propertyValue)
System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(string type, string value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>.CreateAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable<Claim> additionalClaims)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(TUser user, bool isPersistent, string loginProvider, bool bypassTwoFactor)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
```

And the code:

```
public async Task<Response> SignInAsync(SignInDTO signInDTO)
{
    var user = (await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(signInDTO.UserName)) ?? (await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(signInDTO.UserName));

    if (user == null)
        return new Response(false, StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);

    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, signInDTO.Password, false, false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
        return new Response(true, StatusCodes.Status200OK);

    return new Response(false, StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
}
```

Comment: I think the error is on the first line in the function. I think you should use an if statement checking if it is null, but I am not sure.

Comment: The source code for `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` is here. I suggest you dig through your code and see if you can find anywhere you're not setting the various claims values it's trying to assign. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L77-L100

Comment: well actually I am not adding or removing any claim its working with the defaults @MartinCostello

Comment: Lets give it a try... @ken

Comment: @user Sure, but that's what the code throwing the exception is trying to do based on the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the problem.

I am using a base entity which contains the PK of entities.

my user class was having 2 Id prop one from IdentityUser and the other one from BaseEntity so I just removed one of them and now every thing is fine.

thanks to every one , hope it hepls.

Comment: In my case I got this exception because I didn't assign the user a UserName value. For whatever reason UserName is nullable in the default schema, but it really shouldn't be. Adding my comment in case someone else has made the same mistake.